# Can we call ASP.Net page load function from Rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, net-http

I'm facing an issue while calling the ASP.Net function from Rails.
First I want to know that Is it possible to call the ASP.Net function from Rails?

I tried to call it but facing <Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true> error message

I also passed the username and password with it.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems as you like to actually make a HTTP request from a Rails app?
Yes, it is possible. 
Please provide more details, like what you tried, what auth scheme the remote side is using and so on.

Comment: You can create an API in Asp.net application and call it in your Rails app easily, but pls, it's better you say more details about your situation and problem.